# apacite change bibliography webpage url and lastvisited elements print order

Tags: bibliographies, apacite

In order to create a document for my german study, I need to apply a slightly customised version of APA referencing.

In used template, the "accessed at {#1}" text block is printed **before** the url. I need to have it **after** the url, as written manually in the second section *Literatur (target)*. Do you have any advice how to achieve that, preferably while using the latex packages I already have configured? (Italics/Non-italic also differ but doesn't matter).

Rendered document:
[image: Rendered document]

`bib.bib` source code:

```
@webpage{ministerium,
    author = {{Bundesministerium f{\"u}r Familie, Senioren, Frauen und Jugend}},
    lastchecked = {29.09.2022},
    title = {{Stief- und Patchworkfamilien in Deutschland}},
    url = {https://www.bmfsfj.de/resource/blob/76242/ 1ab4cc12c386789b943fc7e12fdef6a1/monitor-familienforschung -ausgabe-31-data.pdf},
    year = {2013},
    bdsk-url-1 = {https://www.bmfsfj.de/resource/blob/76242/%201ab4cc12c386789b943fc7e12fdef6a1/monitor-familienforschung%20-ausgabe-31-data.pdf}}
```

`document.tex` source code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headings=small]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\BRetrieved}[1]{Abgerufen am {#1}, }

Citing of document in APA style \cite[S.~1]{ministerium}, unfortunately with some adaptions. 

It should actually look like \emph{Literatur (target)}, displaying 'abgerufen am 29.09.2022' after url.

\mathchardef\UrlBreakPenalty=200\relax
\raggedright
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mybib.bib}


\section*{Literatur (target)}
\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont\space}
\begin{description}

\item[Bundesministerium für Familie, Senioren, Frauen und Jugend (2013).] Stief- und Patchworkfamilien in Deutschland. https://www.bmfsfj.de/resource/blob/76242/1ab4cc12c386789b943fc7e12fdef6a1/monitor-familienforschung-ausgabe-31-data.pdf,~abgerufen~am~29.09.2022.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend that you (a) switch from apacite/bibtex to biblatex/apa/biber -- mainly so that you can make use of the current-generation APA7 formatting guidelines (apacite implements APA6...) and also get better German-specific adaptations -- and (b) *not* make any idiosyncratic changes to the way the bibliographic entries are formatted by biblatex. Trust me: You may well believe that you're doing something useful here, but no one else will. My apologies if I hurt your feelings.

For this to work properly with biblatex, you will also need to change the field

```
lastchecked = {29.09.2022},
```

to

```
urldate = {2022-09-29},
```

Note the use of the ISO format for the date; this is essential.

To compile the document, you must run latex-biber-latex, *no longer* latex-bibtex-latex-latex.

I would also strongly recommend that you not insert any wanton spaces in URL strings. Instead, do load the `xurl` package, which allows URL strings to be broken at arbitrary places.

[image]

Note the prefix string "Verfügbar 29. September 2022 unter" right before the URL string.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@online{ministerium,
    author = {{Bundesministerium für Familie, Senioren, Frauen und Jugend}},
    title  = {{Stief- und Patchworkfamilien in Deutschland}},
    url    = {https://www.bmfsfj.de/resource/blob/76242/1ab4cc12c386789b943fc7e12fdef6a1/monitor-familienforschung-ausgabe-31-data.pdf},
    year   = {2013},
    urldate = {2022-09-29},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\usepackage{xurl} % <-- important
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for caring for my feelings, that's very kind of you ;) - But most of all thanks for dealing with my issue.

Switching to `biblatex/apa/biber` comes with a slight disadvantage for me: If I use it, the program "Texifier" I use switches to a typesetting mode with less performance. Therefore I tried to avoid it, but if It solves my problem I happily do it.

Unfortunately, my issue is still unsolved - I need to have the "accessed at date" snippet written *after* the URL - not because I like it that way, but because that's a requirement by my tutors. I know it's stupid.

Comment: @ErikTheoboldt - May I suggest that you post a new query, in which you state specifically that you work with biblatex/apa/biber and the `urldate` field, and that you need to change the prefix string "Verfügbar 29. September 2022 unter" to the suffix string ", abgerufen am 29.09.2022"?